# lualatex math tables not working

Tags: luatex, unicode

I just updated MikTeX and found that a .tex file which previously created the right output under lualatex no longer does so. However, xelatex does create the correct output.

The problem seems to be that lualatex is not picking up the opentype MATH tables for stretchy symbols in the Unicode private use area. It works correctly with the standard stretchy symbols such as \left{ and \right}. Note that the \OpnBracS and \ClsBracS have the \left and \right baked in. Those symbols are found in the logix.otf file and the symbols are defined in logix.sty, both of which are in the logix package. Here is some test code.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{logix}
\newcommand \testFrac   {\frac{1}{2+\frac{3}{4}}}
\newcommand \testFrak   {\frac{\frac{\frac{\frac{1}{1}}{\frac{1}{1}}}{\frac{\frac{1}{1}}{\frac{1}{1}}}}{\frac{\frac{\frac{1}{1}}{\frac{1}{1}}}{\frac{\frac{1}{1}}{\frac{1}{1}}}}}

\begin{document}
   $ \OpnBracS \testFrac \ClsBracS $ \hspace{2em} $ \OpnBracS \testFrak \ClsBracS $
   \end{document}
```

This is the output from xelatex

[image]

And here is the output from lualatex

[image]

Comment: open an issue at the luaotfload  github.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know to do that. I have done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was resolved on github. The problem was that the luaotfload package had been "fixed" to resolve a problem with one font that had a minimal MATH table. But that fix broke fonts such as mine which have a valid MATH table, but only for characters in the private use area. There is documentation in the luaotfload package about this, but since I was not directly using that package I did not know to look there.

The solution was to include "Renderer=Basic,Script=Math" where the font is loaded and when LuaLaTeX is used, but not for XeLaTeX. An alternate solution is to include "RawFeature=-nomathparam" which is ignored by XeLaTeX since it doesn't use the luaotfload package. But that assumes implementation details and is probably not a good choice. It actually works with just "Script=Math".